# Trigger a report from a ribbon button

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have several custom reports and I would like to be able to add buttons to the ribbon that trigger them.

Is it possible? And if so, any examples would be great !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run a report from a ribbon button you need to create a js file with a function you'll be calling from your button.

You need 4 things:

1. rdlName - rdl file name.
2. reportGuid GUID of the report.
3. entityGuid = Entity GUID wich you run report for.
4. entityType = Entity Object Type Code.

Here is the example.

```
function printOutOnClick() {
    // This function generates a Print out
    var rdlName = "SomeReport.rdl";
    var reportGuid = "9A984A27-34E5-E011-B68F-005056AC478A";
    var entityGuid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();//Here I am getting Entity GUID it from it's form
    var entityType = "4214";
    var link = serverUrl + "/" + organizationName + "/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&context=records&helpID=" + rdlName  + "&id={" + reportGuid + "}&records=" + entityGuid + "&recordstype=" + entityType;
    openStdDlg(link, null, 800, 600, true, false, null);
}
```

openStdDlg() is the wrapper around window.open() MS Dynamics CRM uses it itself, so do I.

To add it to a ribbon button you need to do like in this post [How to start a Dialog from Application Ribbon (CRM 2011)](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-start-dialog-from-application_08.html) except you need to call report instead a dialog.

Comment: Thank you Grigory ! This is a very helpful snippet and I was actually wondering how to print on click in js!  No problem for the buttons, I've already added a few and created js functions for them.

Comment: Just be careful with using openStdDlg ... technically that is unsupported to use that function I believe.

Answer (score 1):

After the RDL name the Guid should be RecordGuid not EntityGuid

Comment: This was very helpful but I was confused as to the use of the entityType 4214. According to Msoft that is a Service Appointment. The OP asked about reports...I know your snippet was just a sample. But I was unable to find an entitytype for reports...does that mean it can be dropped?