# Dynamics CRM FetchXML Report Event for Plugin to Fire On

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there an event that a plugin can be registered on when a FetchXML (or even SQL) report is run?

RetrieveMultiple and Retrieve do not get fired!

```c#
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    // The FetchXML report does not fire the plugin on RetrieveMultiple
    if (context.InputParameters["Query"] is FetchExpression)
    {
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        using (Context linq = new Context(service))
        {
            // Do the work.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it fire when you do an Advanced Find? Is this registered as a pre or post event plugin? Did you verify it is set to synchronous execution? How have you confirmed it is not running? Have you put a breakpoint on the first line, `IPluginExectionContext...`, to validate that is not firing?

You cannot make a plugin fire when the SQL tables are queried as there is no CRM event that fires. When a FetchXML report is run the RetrieveMultiple event should fire.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @Nick It fires when I do an advanced find, refresh a view, or with a fetchXML query is performed form a console app. I have confirmed that it is not running when the fetchXML report is run - by creating an account before the if and attaching Visual Studio to the sandbox process. The RetrieveMultiple does not seem to fire when the report is run.

Comment: @hkhan I have - a break point is hit when the view is refreshed and when a console app does a fetch query, but not when the fetch report is run!

Comment: @Nicknow It is registered post and synchronous.

Comment: It's possible the fetchXML report uses the deprecated ExecuteFetchRequest message.  Can you register on that and try to hit a breakpoint?  The PluginRegistrationTool won't let you do it, but if you use the CRM developer toolkit to create your plugin, you can edit the "RegisterFile.crmregister" and hardcode the Message name to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution is the following:

> Reports do not trigger plugins. SQL reports bypass CRM completely, and
>   Fetch reports also bypass the plugin pipeline

More about this here: https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/11/25/fetchxml-reports-do-not-trigger-retrievemultiple-plugins-in-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar needs to perform an action when a report is run and the best [supported] way I could find to accomplish this by triggering the report to run via Javascript.

The rough process is this:

1. In the applicable entity, create ribbon button to launch the report via Javascript. (This post gives a how-to: [Trigger a report from a ribbon button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583628/trigger-a-report-from-a-ribbon-button))
2. As part of Javascript function which runs the report, update a field (e.g. "new_ReportRunOn") in the respective record (A standard REST update operation would work here) prior to report run code. The idea here is simply running the report will always cause the "new_ReportRunOn" field to update first.
3. Have your plugin listen for changes on this field by applying a filter only the "new_ReportRunOn" field. (Alternately, you could just have your logic run in Javascript [as part step 2] instead of updating a field just to trigger a plugin.)

This isn't without drawbacks though:

- You would need to "hide" the report in CRM Reports section so it is essentially only accessible via the entity form. It would still be visible in the Reports section if users chose to browse "All Reports" in the reports section. If a "savy" user launched the report this way then it would bypass your Javascript code which fires the plugin.
- If the report can be run across multiple records (e.g. the user selects applicable records from the entity grid view) then additional considerations/coding would need to be done. It is possible to handle this case, but based on your question it doesn't appear this would be use case.

I've had process similar to this in place for a while on our 2013 install and it actually works quite well. It isn't ideal but gets the job done.