# What is the plugin message that triggered when Dynamics CRM FetchXml report executes

Tags: events, plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I created "Retrieve" and "Retrieve Multiple" CRM plugins on Dynamics CRM 2016 V8.2, to perform data decryption on one of the custom fields.
This plugin works fine on List View, Advanced Find, Forms but the plugins not triggered when the FetchXML report executes on the same entity and custom field.
Any advise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM FetchXML Report Event for Plugin to Fire On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866176/dynamics-crm-fetchxml-report-event-for-plugin-to-fire-on)

Answer (score 0):

Reports are bypassing Plugin execution. Please find the Details Here [Dynamics CRM FetchXML Report Event for Plugin to Fire On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866176/dynamics-crm-fetchxml-report-event-for-plugin-to-fire-on)